# Error regarding property while trying to connect NetSuite database in Datagrip

Tags: jdbc, netsuite, datagrip

I'm getting the following error while trying to connect to NetSuite via Datagrip

[S1000][217] [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Property '' should be number. Error ticket# lnwks1dwgah4nfcd22pb[217].

I've downloaded NetSuite's JDBC Driver

Since NetSuite2.com is not accessible for the SuiteAnalytics role, I've created a new Role and a new User as well

I'm using Username and Password to authenticate

Comment: This seems to be a driver-related issue. Please report your issue on our tracker

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

and include the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. The problem was that in the URL where I listed Account and Role properties, there was a white space

Comment: Also, please upvote the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17877/Oracle-NetSuite-support-in-Datagrip

Answer (score 0):

IDE doesn't trim JDBC URL and use it as is.
Try to remove any extra spaces from JDBC URL.